# C++ Nice "name" for own function

Tags: c++, class

I have a class in C++ (VS2010).

This class has public functions, for example "ToString".

Sometimes it happens that I need to call ToString from within the class.

For example:

```
void::ConvertToLowerCase()
{
    wstring ws;
    ws = ToString();
    ws = lower(ws);
    m_wsText= ws
}
```

I would like to know if I can add an "owner" to the ToString line, for example

```
ws = self.ToString();
```

or

```
ws = me.ToString();
```

I tried all names that I could imagine, but I did not find any that would work.
Having such an owner name helps me to figure out where the function resides.

Comment: Or just start using Objective-C, and you will instantly *have to* explicitly call `[self toString]`...

Comment: `#define self (*this)` and you can write `self.ToString()` 8-)

Comment: what is `void::ConvertToLowerCase()` supposed to do?

Comment: I suggest you head over to [this book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and get one of the introductory texts as quick as you can.

Comment: And the -1s are for what?

Comment: @Spook probably lack of research.

Comment: And the +1s are for what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ you can do this via `this`:

```
ws = this->ToString(); //this is a pointer
```

but called in that context, this is equivalent to what you already have:

```
ws = ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` pointer:

```
ws = this->ToString();
```